# Building a dataframe in and outputting it from a for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Basically, I am trying to make a function that will generate a loess model, and then predict the values of the model over a specified range, and output it to a dataframe. I have different function using the same general structure that outputs the data frame I build, but this one doesn't seem to be working and I cannot figure out why. I assume it is embarrassingly simple.

Make some fake data

```
mod<-data.frame(k1=c(200:600), a=rnorm(401, 20,5), b=rnorm(401, 20,5), c=rnorm(401, 20,5),
                k2=c(200:600), d=rnorm(401, 20,5), e=rnorm(401, 20,5), f=rnorm(401, 20,5))
```

Remove any leftover variables

```
rm(pred_a, a.pred, a.loess)
```

Generate a function to loop through the dataframe, perform loess, and output the predicitons to an object that can be used later on. "s" is a variable that the user needs to be able to modify.

```
nofun<-function(mod, s=rep(0.5,(dim(mod)[[2]]-2))){
  d<-dim(mod)[[2]]
```

extract relevant portion of data frame

```
 mod_a<-mod[,1:(d/2)]
```

create a variable for prediciton

```
  k<-c(200:600)
```

Create an empty data frame

```
 pred_a<-data.frame(k)
```

Assign the predict output to a dataframe or matrix. This seems to be working if I wrap the 5th line in a print() statement (i.e it outputs the right data to the console), but it won't create the variable in the workspace.

```
for(i in 1:(d/2-1)){
    a.loess<-loess(mod_a[,i+1] ~ mod_a[,1], span=s[i], data=mod_a)
    a.pred <-predict(a.loess,k)
    a.pred[a.pred<0]<-0
    pred_a<-cbind(pred_a, a.pred)
  }
 }
nofun(mod)
```

This returns "Error: object 'pred_a' not found"

```
pred_a
```

Comment: This doesn't return an error for me. However, `nofun` is missing a return value. Add `pred_a` before the final `}`.

Comment: Right, but that just outputs to the console. If I run nofun(mod), i will see the output.  If I then type pred_a.  That output was not captured ("Error: object 'pred_a' not found").  I could get around this by just typing pred_a<-nofun(mod) when I got to run the model, but I would like it just to create the model object when I run simply nofun(mod).

Comment: Although the latter is possible, it's very much against the concepts of the language. Functions should only have a return value, which you can then assign to variables, and no side effects (like creating an R object). So, use `pred_a <- nofun(mod)`.